# Splitting Values in Dataweave Mule 4

Tags: transform, dataweave, mule4

I am trying to split input values using Regex.
My input will be like this

"salesforce.com/jobs/2020/06-2020"

the expression am using is below

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
"FName": vars.Folderstruct splitBy(/[\/]/)
```

Output:

```
{
  "FName": [
    "salesforce.com",
    "jobs",
    "2020",
    "06-2020"
  ]
}
```

But i need my output like this

```
{
    "FName":"salesforce.com"
},
{
    "FName":"jobs"
},
{
    "FName":"2020"
},
{
    "FName":"06-2020"
}
```

How can i achieve this through transform?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the list with values, what you need is to create a new object with each one, and for that, you can use the map function like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
vars.Folderstruct splitBy(/[\/]/) map ((item, index) -> 
  {
    FName: item
  }
)
```